# GIS in Python. Linking two GeoJSON data files

Tags: python, gis, geojson

I am new to using GIS data in python. I have two datasets in GeoJSON format. One of them has states of a country with multi-polygons representing each states. The other has multiple points of latitudes and longitudes, each one describing a particular branch information(also in the same country).

I am looking to integrate these two geojson files so that i can get something like  all the branches or the number of branches located in a particular state.

Please suggest how this can be done in python.

Comment: Have you considered asking this question on [gis.se]?

Comment: I will post the question there too. Thank you

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc